# Another mod rewrite question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to turn my url in example 1 to example 2 using mod_rewrite but with no success? I'm using godaddy.

Example 1

```
http://www.example.com/categories/details.php?cat=fruit
```

Example 2

```
http://www.example.com/categories/fruit/
```

Here is my mod rewrite code in my categories folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /categories/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/categories/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ http://www.example.com/categories/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^details\.php$ http://www.example.com/categories/%1.php [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^categories\/details\.php$ http://www.example.com/categories/%1 [R=302,L]
```

This:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Should match the query. So it should find cat in the beginning of the query and match the group after cat which is the var. Now you can also match the sub categories too.
To match multiple ones you could do something like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\&sub1=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\&sub1=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\&sub2=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

And then you could use %1,%2,%3 as your variables.

This:

```
RewriteRule ^categories\/details\.php$ http://www.example.com/categories/%1 [R=302,L]
```

Will match the entire URL minus the domain. And you use %1 to get the group from the rewritecond.

=============== OLD ===============

I'm not very good with regex, but ^ will match the beginning of a line. So try this out.

```
^categories\/details\.php\?cat=(.*)$

Then you will need to use http://www.example.com/categories/$1
```

If you need me to explain the regex to you let me know. This is simple enough so that i can explain it.

you can replace this portion:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^details\.php$ http://www.example.com/categories/%1.php [R=302,L]
```

with:

```
RewriteRule ^categories\/details\.php\?cat=(.*)$ http://www.example.com/categories/$1
```

I can't exactly remember how mod_rewrite works, so i don't want to give you bad information using rewriteCond.

Ok so using what you had before. Try to just add the categories on to it.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^categories\/details\.php$ http://www.example.com/categories/%1 [R=302,L]
```

Also a note:

I would probably use + instead of * as well. So ^?cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^categories\/details\.php$ http://www.example.com/categories/%2 [L]
```

Comment: ok im looking at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString so ill update post and see if that works.

Comment: @Matt now I get an 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: hmmm, one of those should work. Let me see if i can find something real quick

Comment: @maximum do you have any other variables set. Like is it just cat or are there other elements in there?

Comment: @Matt there are other variables like `&sub1=apple&sub2=green` when clicked on a new sub category.

Comment: @maximum join me the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/431/apache or search for apache

Comment: @maximum oh noes!! ok. post an example of the exact URL, you can substitute the domain name if you wish.

Comment: here is an example `http://www.example.com/categories/details.php?cat=fruit&sub1=apple&sub2=green`

Comment: I still can't get it to work:( thanks for all the help though.

Comment: @maximum you can also try this: `RewriteRule /categories/details.php\?cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]+) http://www.example.com/categories/$1` If that doesn't work then im not sure.